# How to pass parameter to route matcher function in Angular 9?

Tags: angular

The `UrlMatcher` API has changed in Angular 9. I was passing a parameter to the matcher helper function as follow in Angular  8:

```
export function matcherHelper(segments: UrlSegment[], providerParam) {
  //... Logic here
  return ....;
}
```

Route:

```
{
  matcher: (url) => matcherHelper(url, 'xxx'),
  loadChildren: () => import('./xxx/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
}
```

But the above is changed to the following in Angular 9:

```
{
  matcher: matcherHelper('xxx'),
  loadChildren: () => import('./xxx/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
}
```

In the above, the `UrlSegment[]` is passed as the first parameter by default, but since I have two parameters the syntax is invalid because the helper function expects two parameters instead of one.

It only works if I use it as below without any parameter (UrlSegment is passed by default int the following route):

```
{
  matcher: matcherHelper,
 loadChildren: () => import('./xxx/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to pass to the matcher, and where is it coming from?

Comment: @FrisoHoekstra It's static string passing here: `matcherHelper('xxx')`

Comment: Since the API doesn't allow you to pass anything other than the `UrlSegments`, can't you just pass it as a query parameter? `&providerParam='xxx'`

Comment: @FrisoHoekstra How to pass as query parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround for this is to create a wrapper for the match helper function. The only drawback is to have one wrapper for each route.

```
export function firstMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]) {
  return matcherHelper(segments, 'firstParam')
}

export function secondMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]) {
  return matcherHelper(segments, 'secondParam')
}

export function matcherHelper(segments: UrlSegment[], providerParam) {
  // Logic and return
}
```

Comment: Would just remove the `export` from `matcherHelper`

Comment: @Richard right, since we are not exporting it to elsewhere.

Comment: yeah it's basically an "abstract function", although there is no such thing 

Answer (score 0):

The `UrlMatcher` API should only be used when Angular's default matching patterns are not sufficient.

If you need to pass **static** data, you can try this:

```
{
    path: 'somePath',
    component: SomeComponent,
    data: { string: 'xxx' }
 }
```

If you are looking to pass a string variable, you could pass it as part of the URL and then match against that using `path`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/somePath', 'xxx']">
```

and then:

```
{ path: 'somePath/:string', component: SomeComponent }
```

You can also pass it as a `queryParam`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/somePath']" [queryParams]="{ string: 'xxx'}">
```

This will result in the following URL:

```
http://yourHost/somePath?string:xxx
```

There are many more possible routing strategies. **Read the docs**. If your data needs to come from some API, you can use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have to use `UrlMatcher` since I have a complicated situation. I have many domains or subdomains serving the same app. I am identifying the domain and then setting a route based on that one. My purpose is not to pass data to the route but the reason I am passing the parameter to the matcher helper function is to understand which route I am evaluating.

Comment: That sounds like something your web server (apache, nginx, caddy) should handle.

Comment: I am serving different layouts based on the `URL` which makes it complicated. Using Windows Server. Will see how that helps.